# Jhipster gateway forwarding and timeout error

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

i am using jhipster and gateway while uploading a file its take time for response, but gateway already given exception message timeout and forwarding error tried multiple thing but didn't work

### In application properties i already tried,

```
zuul:
    host:
        connect-timeout-millis: 10000
        socket-timeout-millis: 10000

hystrix:
    command:
        default:
            execution:
                timeout:
                    enabled: false
```

---

```
zuul:
    host:
        connect-timeout-millis: 10000
        socket-timeout-millis: 10000

hystrix:
    command:
        default:
            execution:
                isolation:
                    thread:
                        timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
```

---

> 2018-10-03 16:09:10.621 DEBUG 13048 --- [  XNIO-5 task-1]
>   c.c.w.g.a.AccessControlFilter            : Access Control: allowing
>   access for /core/api/ci/upload/file, as no access control policy has
>   been set up for service: core 2018-10-03 16:09:15.726  WARN 13048 ---
>   [  XNIO-5 task-1] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error
>   during filtering
>
> com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:188)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:163)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:111)
>           at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112)
>           at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193)
>           at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157)
>           at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118)
>           at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96)
>           at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116)
>           at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>           at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:111)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>           at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at com.xxx.web.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:45)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:64)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>           at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:336)
>           at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: null
>           at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:123)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:105)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:43)
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302)
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>           at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10307)
>           at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10274)
>           at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:51)
>           at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:412)
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:378)
>           at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:344)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:157)
>           ... 114 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read
>   timed out
>           at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:58)
>           at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:465)
>           at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:342)
>           at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:117)
>           ... 174 common frames omitted Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165)
>           at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
>           at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient$1.doWithRetry(RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:93)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient$1.doWithRetry(RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:71)
>           at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
>           at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.executeWithRetry(RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:113)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.execute(RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:104)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.execute(RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:50)
>           at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient$1.call(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:109)
>           at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:303)
>           at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:287)
>           at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:231)
>           at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:228)
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.drain(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:286)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:144)
>           at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:185)
>           at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180)
>           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
>           at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
>           at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10307)
>           at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10274)
>           at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:445)
>           ... 176 common frames omitted

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/321

Comment: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3323

Answer (score 8):

after a lot of test and search i found a solution, we also need to configure and increase ribbon timeout in mili.

```
hystrix:
    command:
        default:
            execution:
                isolation:
                    thread:
                        timeoutInMilliseconds: 30000
ribbon:
    ReadTimeout: 60000
    ConnectionTimeout: 3000
    eureka:
        enabled: true
zuul:
    host:
        connect-timeout-millis: 5000
        max-per-route-connections: 10000
        max-total-connections: 5000
        socket-timeout-millis: 60000
    semaphore:
        max-semaphores: 500
```